# How to make a numbers triangle in Java using loops, numbers starting from right

Tags: java

my project to create a triangle in Java with numbers starting from the right

[image]

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Pyramid {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

      // loop
      for (int i=1; i <= 6; i++) {
         // space
         for(int j=1; j <= 6-i; j++)
         System.out.print(" ");

         // numbers
         for(int k= 1; k <= i; k++)
         System.out.print(k);

         // new line
         System.out.println();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: remember, it goes from left to right. In loop, start `k=i`, then decrement it util less than 1.

Comment: where is the problem? Your code works

Comment: @OrangoMango No it doesn't.  Look carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way.  It uses `String.repeat()` to pad with leading spaces.

- outer loop controls the rows.
- Then print the leading spaces
- inner loop iterates backwards, printing the value and a space
- then print a newline

```
int rows = 6;
for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
    System.out.print("  ".repeat(rows-i));
    for (int k = i; k > 0; k--) {
        System.out.print(k+ " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

prints

```
          1 
        2 1 
      3 2 1 
    4 3 2 1 
  5 4 3 2 1 
6 5 4 3 2 1
```

If you don't want to use `String.repeat()` then use a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Well the only thing you have to do is change order like you are first adding space and then number instead add number and then space.
code -

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Pyramid {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

      // loop
      for (int i=1; i <= 6; i++) {
          // numbers
         for(int k= 1; k <= i; k++)
         System.out.print(k);
         
         // space
         for(int j=1; j <= 6-i; j++)
         System.out.print(" ");
         
         // new line
         System.out.println();

      }
  }
}
```

Now we get the result -

[image: Pyramid right to left.]

Comment: The asker wants his numbers to start from the right.

Comment: oh sorry i forgot to notice that but if he wants that then his code already works @AliasCartellano

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pyramid {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int lines = scanner.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i <= lines; i++) {
            //space
            int spaceNum = lines - I;
            for (int j = 0; j < spaceNum; j++) {
                System.out.print("  ");
            }
            //numbers
            int numbers = lines - spaceNum;
            for (int j = numbers; j > 0; j--) {
                System.out.print(" " + j);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This would not work for numbers with more than one digit, the alignment would be off, try with a number such as 15.

Answer (score 0):

start `k=i` then decrement it till `k>=1`.

```java
for(int k= i; k >=1 ; k--)
     System.out.print(k+" ");
```

output

```
          1 
        2 1 
      3 2 1 
    4 3 2 1 
  5 4 3 2 1 
6 5 4 3 2 1
```